# What's the law of Bittul and powdered milk?

Tags: halacha, meat-and-milk, bitul-batel-null

Suppose someone took a tea-spoon of powdered milk, reconstituted it into normal milk, and accidentally dropped some of it on meat. Do we measure the bittul of the resulting mixture against the powder or against the "reconstitution"?

Comment: You taste it...

Comment: @Double why would you say something like that?

Comment: @user6591 To see if it's batel?

Comment: @Double Who tastes food nowadays to see if its batul?

Comment: @Double And by nowadays I mean more than just post Maharam Padowa as brought in the Ramma saying we don't do this anymore. I mean post Kaf HaChaim saying that even Sfardim can't do taste tests anymore, and even Chacham Ovadia who thought that was too 'Ashkenized' of a psak, still agreed that unless its a hefsed meruba, one should not do it.

Comment: That should have said Kaf HaChaim quoting Ben Ish Chai

Answer (score 2):

The [OU](http://oukosher.org/blog/kosher-professionals/bitul/) says that powdered milk, when evaluating bittul, they look at the powdered form, not the reconstructed amount (unlike grape juice concentrate where they look at the volume when reconstructed).

However, in the case you present, the milk was reconstructed prior. That is more a case of Chanan, [which does not apply here](http://oukosher.org/blog/kosher-professionals/lo-basi-ella-lorer-limitations-of-chanan/) because it only applies to Issur (which youre case is ostensibly not) and even if the milk was not Cholov Yisroel, according to the OU anyway.

Comment: Why is not like a _tavlin_? (or from the other perspective, why not always evaluate milk by it's powered equivalent?) I don't know why you have to get into Chanan. The added water doesn't add any flavor at all. Even if the water becomes chanamilchig it's batel berov.

Comment: @DoubleAA, re: *Tavlin*, the OU compares it to cheese - the fact that it is more concentrated doesn't change the bittul calculations. Re the other perspective, all estimates of 60 are on the thing, not some theoretically concentrated but of equal potency equivalent. I don't understand why you think the water is bottul.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the reconstitution. "Foodstuffs" are batel 1:60 by volume. "Flavorings" aren't batel until you really can't taste them. The question is which way concentrates go -- and I assume powdered milk is stronger than a "foodstuff."

The question came up with regards to some beer that was being run on the same line as ... clam juice, I think? Some of the ingredients were concentrated, so the question of bitul came up there.